# How to include a site column for year that can be populated using the standard calendar

Tags: 2013, development, date-time, list-form, site-column

I am working on an on-premises SharePoint 2013 farm. We need to have a site column which represents the "Date Published" for books and papers where we need to store a value representing the year. Is there a way to have a field of type `date` which only renders the year?

I read that I can define a calculated column, but what I am trying to achieve is to have a column which will be populated using the standard calendar (inside the quick edit grid, create & edit list forms) but the calendar would only contain the year. Is that possible?

Comment: It's better to have a Choice column and fill it with all possible values.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri i was thinking of this option, so i will create a drop-down list , with value starting from 1900 till 2050 ??

Comment: Yes that should work